# remove the word "reply" in the comments

Tags: php, wordpress, function, comments, reply

I am working on the SEO of my site and in some pages and articles I have comments, but I would like to keep the "reply" function but remove unnecessary code like:

```
<div class="meta-info">
    <header class="row no-margin">
        <div class="pull-left flip">
            <span class="author">rodrigue7973ro</span>
            <span class="date">28 janvier 2019</span>
            <div class="pull-right flip">
                <a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='#comment-4425' data-commentid="4425" data-postid="4488" data-belowelement="comment-4425" data-respondelement="respond" data-replyto="Répondre à rodrigue7973ro" aria-label='Répondre à rodrigue7973ro'>Répondre</a> 
                <span>&darr;</span>                             
            </div><!-- /.pull-right -->
    </header><!-- /.row -->
</div><!-- /.meta-info -->
```

exemple de l'url : https://www.boutique-pcland.fr/telecharger-iso-de-windows-7-8-1-10-server/view-source:https://www.boutique-pcland.fr/telecharger-iso-de-windows-7-8-1-10-server/ (search answer)

i am using wordpress and i already have code like:

````
//MediaCenter - Post commet function
function media_center_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    switch ( $comment->comment_type ) :
        case 'pingback' :
        case 'trackback' :
        // Display trackbacks differently than normal comments.
    ?>
    <li <?php comment_class('comment-item'); ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        <p><?php _e( 'Pingback:', 'mediacenter' ); ?> <?php comment_author_link(); ?> <?php edit_comment_link( __( '(Edit)', 'mediacenter' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?></p>
    <?php
            break;
        default :
        // Proceed with normal comments.
        global $post;
    ?>
        <li <?php comment_class('comment-item'); ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">

            <div class="row no-margin">
                
                <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-2 no-margin">
                    <div class="avatar icon-overlay icn-link">
                        <?php echo get_avatar( $comment->comment_author_email , 70 );?>
                    </div><!-- /.avatar -->
                </div><!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-11 col-sm-10 no-margin-right">
                    <div class="comment-body">
                        
                        <div class="meta-info">
                            <header class="row no-margin">
                                <div class="pull-left flip">
                                    <span class="author"><?php echo get_comment_author_link(); ?></span>
                                    <?php if( $comment->user_id === $post->post_author ): ?>
                                        <span class="label label-default"><?php echo __( 'Post author', 'mediacenter' ); ?></span>
                                    <?php endif;?>
                                    <?php if ( '0' == $comment->comment_approved ) : ?>
                                        <span class="label label-danger"><?php _e( 'Awaiting moderation.', 'mediacenter' ); ?></span>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <span class="date"><?php echo get_comment_date(); ?></span>
                                <div class="pull-right flip">
                                    <?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'reply_text' => __( 'Reply', 'mediacenter' ), 'after' => ' <span>&darr;</span>', 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>
                                </div><!-- /.pull-right -->
                            </header><!-- /.row -->
                            
                        </div><!-- /.meta-info -->

                        <div class="comment-content"><?php comment_text(); ?></div>

                    </div><!-- /.comment-body -->
                </div><!-- /.col -->

            </div><!-- /.row -->

        </li><!-- /.comment -->
            <?php
        break;
    endswitch; // end comment_type check
}```

Thank you for your help
````

Answer (score 1):

in fact I have to modify this line:

````
<?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'reply_text' => __( 'Reply', 'mediacenter' ), 'after' => ' <span>&darr;</span>', 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>```
````